# PHP PDO forcing SQL99

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am connecting to a MySQL database with the following using PDO.

```
    try {
        $this->myDBH = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
        $this->myDBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $cameralife->error('Database error: ' . htmlentities($e->getMessage()));
    }
```

Can I enable a "strict" SQL-99 compliance mode that will reject any query that does not follow that standard?

Comment: [Good luck with that.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/compatibility.html)

Comment: I am using this as a first step in lessening dependence on MySQL and allowing the PDO to connect to SQLite

Comment: Actually, SQLite's incarnation of SQL is closer to MySQL's than SQL-99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the mysql `sql_mode` with a query like

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'xxx'
```

where xxx is one of the [valid sql modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html).

There is an [`ansi` sql mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi), which makes MySQL behave more like a standard compliant DBMS. Although it is just "more like" not "as".

You can read about the possible sql modes [in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-combo). The combined sql modes are the interesting ones.

There is also a manual page dedicated to [standards compliance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/compatibility.html), which names `sql_mode="ansi"` as one option.

I do not know of a way to achieve something similar with pure PDO and/or without this setting.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. PDO does not parse, enforce, or rewrite SQL syntax. Except for allowing named query parameters, which are *not* SQL-99 standard.

As @GhostGambler answered, MySQL has an `SQL_MODE` variable that lets us enable a few features of syntax and semantics to conform to SQL-99 a bit better, but this is incomplete.

Even when `SQL_MODE=ANSI`, MySQL still allows many MySQL-specific features that are not SQL-99. For example:

- `REPLACE`
- `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`
- `INSERT...SET column=value`
- `LIMIT` clause
- Multi-table joined `UPDATE` and `DELETE`
- Most of the built-in SQL functions
- `CREATE TABLE` options
- Data types like `SET` and `ENUM`
- etc.

You wouldn't want to reject *any* query that doesn't follow SQL-99 anyway. For instance, that would mean you wouldn't be able to `CREATE INDEX` (indexes in general, and any statements needed to manage them, are left as an implementation detail, not specified by the SQL standard).